# Do curved treadmills help with proper running form?

Tags: running, cardio, training, treadmill

Do curved treadmills help with proper running form*?

In looking for a treadmill, I came across curved treadmills like the Woodway Curve and TrueForm Runner. They claim to help with form, but do they really? I’d like to find out before dropping $5000+ (or would I be better off with another treadmill?)

- I realize that “proper running form” can vary between individuals, but I believe we could all agree that, undeniably, there are general good rules of thumb to follow (ie. Maintaining a short, quick stride, keeping your knees in line, etc)

Comment: A reference to what you mean by "*proper* running form" might help potential respondents.

Answer (score 2):

A curved treadmill will not help you "maintain a short, quick stride".  In fact, unless you modify your stride specifically for that treadmill's curvature, your stride will be *longer*: your feet will maintain contact with the treadmill through a longer arc (range of motion).

If you intend to improve your form for running on normal (that is, "flat") surfaces, then I fail to see how a curved treadmill will help you.